# meaning of this sentence 'the children carried their life-story no further on his behoof'?

Tags: meaning

The children in question were a standing puzzle to Octavian; in the course of a few months he considered that he should have known their names, ages, the dates of their birthdays, and have been introduced to their favourite toys. They remained however, as non-committal as the long blank wall that shut them off from the meadow, a wall over which their three heads sometimes appeared at odd moments. They had parents in India -- that much Octavian had learned in the neighbourhood; **the children, beyond grouping themselves garment-wise into sexes, a girl and two boys, carried their life-story no further on his behoof.** And now it seemed he was engaged in something which touched them closely, but must be hidden from their knowledge.

It's from Hector Hugh Munro's (Saki) "Penance".

Expecting some help to understand the meaning of the above sentence of **~**.

Comment: Is it really "behoof" and not "behalf"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saki is saying that aside from obviously identifying their sexes, the children were almost entirely uncommunicative toward Octavian.

Comment: IIRC this is the one where he is termed "un-beast" at the end? I can remember the gist, not specifics, but I think there's a cat involved.